# Not able to execute selenium script on jenkins on chrome version 73

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Since chrome got updated to version 73, My scripts which were working fine on jenkins on for previous versions of chrome, are now stopped working, So if anyone had same issue and able to find solution for that, please share it. Thanks.

I have already tried with trying different versions of chromedriver, but no luck on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found in the ChromeDrivers site, Please see if this resolves the issue.

If you are using Chrome version 73, please download ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: I already have used it but no luck with that also.

Comment: Posting some error details will be helpful.